# Anchor tags not working in CMS (ModX)

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor, modx, modx-revolution

I am using the latest ModX Revolution CMS which has both a dynamically created menu and content.

I have my menu set up as such:

```
<a href="#aboutus">About Us</a>
```

And, in my content:

```
<a name="aboutus" id="aboutus"><h1>About us</h1></a>
```

But upon clicking the links I just get 404s.

Is there a problem with this being dynamically created content?

(PS: FURLs are active)

EDIT: Not a proper answer but got it working by using:

```
  var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```

To add the current pages url to my anchor links.

Would still like to know the proper way of doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was not working for me is that I was not using FURLs so my URLs looked like:

```
mysite.com/index.html?id=2
```

It was the PHP vars that were not being included in the url and thus throwing a 404.

I amended this by using JQuery to add the entire path name to my links:

```
var fullurl = window.location.href
```

Answer (score 1):

To add the current page url to your anchor in the proper modx way, your link should be something like this:

```
<a href="[[*alias]]#aboutus">
```

If FURLs are NOT active you can add ".html" to your link:

```
<a href="[[*alias]].html#aboutus">
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Check your base url meta tag, & see if you are using [[++site_url]] or [[++base_url]] & then check if they are correct in the system settings.